# How do I pass *args and **kwargs to a python script at the same time from the command-line

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I can't figure out how to pass both *args and **kwargs to a python script from the cli.*args seems to include **kwargs entries the way I'm doing it. Am I supposed to figure out how many **kwargs there are then subtract that number from the *args to determine which arguments were args?

I can do it by passing to the function from within the script, but if I want to pass in arguments from the cli, how do I identify which ones are for *args and which are for **kwargs?

This works:

```
def Func(*args,**kwargs):

    for arg in args:
        print arg
    for item in kwargs.items():
        print item

print Func(1,2,3,x=7,u=8)
```

But I want something like this:

```
def Func(*args,**kwargs):

    for arg in args:
        print arg
    for item in kwargs.items():
        print item

print Func(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3:])
```

This is what I get:

```
$ ./test.py 1 2 3 4 x=7 u=8

1
2
['3', '4', 'x=7', 'u=8']
None
```

But I want to get something closer to this:

```
$ ./test.py 1 2 3 4 x=7 u=8
1
2
['3', '4']
{'x': '7', 'u': '8'}
```

or this:

```
$ ./test.py 1 2 3 4 x=7 u=8

1
2
3
4
('x', 7)
('u', 8)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html out. It's a nice library for working with command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out in more detail but it seems to be a bit of overkill for what I need. Are you saying I can't do what I want to do on my own, natively with sys.argv?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment by @kingforever above, using the argparse module would be much cleaner and more safe (checking mandatory arguments, argument validity etc).

Anyway, one possible lightweight quick solution you ask for would be:

```
args = [x for x in sys.argv if '=' not in x]                                     
kwargs = {x.split('=')[0]: x.split('=')[1] for x in sys.argv if '=' in x}        
print Func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see now how that could work. Another solution that could work would be to pass in a string with comma separated values, grab it with sys,argv[3], then split the values out. Is that considered acceptable or stupid?!